# How I can call properties into .robot file in robot framework? Im doing the scripting in PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

This is the program I implemented into my `TestObject.py` file

```
import random
import sys
import os

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.setX(x)

    def getX(self):
        return self.x
    def setX(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.x = 1000
        else:
            self.x= x
```

I want to call the above code into my suite where I implemented the keywords "robot framework".

How can I instantiate the objects of the above class into the robot file.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ../../ObjectsRepository/EngageAO/TestObject.py
```

I'm not getting how I can call fields, variables, functions into the `.robot` file

Comment: Note :   .py and .robot file belongs to same suite.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you have it set up, *and assuming the folder that contains this module is on your python path*, you can import the class like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | TestObject.MyClass
```

The methods of this class will then become keywords, eg:

```
*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | SetX | 10
```

If the path that contains the file is not on your python path, you cannot both specify the path to the file and import arbitrary classes within the file.

A common solution is for your file to have a class that that has the same name as the filename. In your case you would name the class `TestObject`, or name the file `MyClass.py`. When you do this, robot will automatically create an instance of the class and make all of the methods available as keywords.

This is documented in the section [Creating test library class or module](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id674) of the robot framework user guide.

Comment: Hi Bryan, i am bit confusing about the python path. Python i have installed at c:\ while project i have kept at d:\ location. while the file which i am trying to import is from d:\ of same directory. Below is the code *** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library    MyLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    Do Nothing                 ->>>>> method implemented into MyLibrary 
    Hello    world              ->>>>> method implemented into MyLibrary both method i am unable to call into .robot file

Answer (score 0):

I think class name and file name must be the same
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html
"If the modifier is given as a path, the class name must be same as the file name."

Btw, if we didn't define getX function, do you have anyway to get x value?